# Merging List of JSONs into one JSON in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have an HTML form and I'm trying to stringify and parse its content into JSON on submission using javascript

for example:

```
<form id="form1" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="presented" value="1" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="RESPONSE" value="ch1">ch1</input>
    <input type="checkbox" name="RESPONSE" value="ch2">ch2</input>
    <input type="checkbox" name="RESPONSE" value="ch3">ch3</input>

    <input id="submit_button" name="submit" type="submit"/>
</form>
```

and the javascript:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#submit_button").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var formData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(jQuery('#form1').serializeArray()));
        alert(JSON.stringify(formData));
    });
});
```

I'm getting an output like this (considering that only the first two checkboxes are checked):

```
[{"name":"presented","value":"1"},
 {"name":"RESPONSE","value":"ch1"},
 {"name":"RESPONSE","value":"ch2"}]
```

but I'm expecting this result in one JSON with arrays for duplicated keys:

```
{"presented" : "1", "RESPONSE" : ["ch1", "ch2"]}
```

jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/052wjq1m/3/)

Comment: Input elements can't have child nodes or end tags. Please [learn to love labels](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200711/use_the_label_element_to_make_your_html_forms_accessible/)

Comment: You are getting the expected output from serializeArray. If you want a different data structure, then you need to build it yourself or find a different library function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to write your own serializer. For example to group values of the elements with the same name you could do something like this using `Array.prototype.reduce`:

```js
$("#submit_button").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var formData = jQuery('#form1').serializeArray().reduce(function(prev, curr) {
        if (prev.hasOwnProperty(curr.name)) {
            prev[curr.name] = $.isArray(prev[curr.name]) ? prev[curr.name] : [prev[curr.name]]
            prev[curr.name].push(curr.value);
        }
        else {
            prev[curr.name] = curr.value;
        }
        return prev;
    }, {});
    document.querySelector('pre').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(formData, null, 4);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form1" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="presented" value="1" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="RESPONSE" value="ch1">ch1</input>
    <input type="checkbox" name="RESPONSE" value="ch2">ch2</input>
    <input type="checkbox" name="RESPONSE" value="ch3">ch3</input>
    
    <input id="submit_button" name="submit" type="submit"/>
</form>

<pre></pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that your new object's value should always be an array for consistency. Here's how to build it:

```
var arr = [{"name":"presented","value":"1"},
 {"name":"RESPONSE","value":"ch1"},
 {"name":"RESPONSE","value":"ch2"}];

var newObj = {};
arr.forEach(function(item){
    if(!newObj.hasOwnProperty(item.name)){
        newObj[item.name] = [];
    }

    newObj[item.name].push(item.value);
});
```

And here's a way to build it exactly like you want it:

```
var newObj = {};
arr.forEach(function (item) {
    if (!newObj.hasOwnProperty(item.name)) {
        newObj[item.name] = item.value;
    } else {
        if (Object.prototype.toString.call(newObj[item.name]) !== '[object Array]') {
            var newItem = newObj[item.name];
            newObj[item.name] = [newItem];
        }
        newObj[item.name].push(item.value);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Think other than JSON parsing library. It's very simple Java Program using String.split() method that convert Json String into name> without using any library.